# Javascript/CSS/PHP Hoverbox with various locations on mouseover

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to get various locations to appear on a image with mouseovers. So basically I have an image and when you hover over a link nearby a hoverbox appears at the location specified in CSS on the image. However I'm trying to get it to happen with multiple links without creating code for each CSS box.

I have something like 50 links and and when I hover over one I want to be able to pull from a db or text file to grab the location where it should create a hover on the image. My original thought was using PHP to help pull in the information from a file, put it into an array and then having the CSS update on the fly. This seems doable if the user just clicks the link as then I can tell CSS what place in the array to look for the location. I am unsure how I could get this to work with mouseovers if at all possible.

The CSS code is very basic at the moment as shown below. 
`#box {
position: absolute;
top: 100px;
left: 200px;
background-color: #ffffff;}`

Let me know if anything doesn't make sense or if I'm just forgetting something.

Thank you!

Comment: is this feature like facebook image tagging? like, are the links and image separate from each other, and then something appears over the image when the user does a mouseover on the link?

Comment: I guess so it does. Just instead of a huge box around the person, I'm either going for a text box or an image of like an arrow per say to a point on the map. As an example lets say you have a map of the city you live in and there are various POI, lots of them right next to each other(like stores or what have you). I'm looking for a method so I can hover over a link and display lets say an arrow to that POI on the map. The map is just a basic 500x500 image but can have lots of POI near each other.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so what you're trying to do is called a CSS sprite. Here's what you want (my example is orthogonal to your code, but teaches the principle):

```
.link {
    width: 50px;
    heigh: 50px;
    float: left;
    text-indent: -9000px;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url(path/to/sprite.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

    .link#one {
        background-position: 0px 0px; /* This one is top left on the image. */
    }

    .link#two {
        background-position: 0px 50px; /* This one is 50px from top and 0px from left on the image. */
    }
```

You can see where to go from here (and you don't need to use `.link#one`. I just used it for example purposes. You could just use `#one`, or even a class `.one`.

Practice with this and you'll get how it works soon enough. Here's some sample HTML:

```
<a id="one" class="link">One</a>
<a id="two" class="link">Two</a>
```

Just through all that together, and make your image a 100px tall by 50px wide .png file with 50px x 50px for each link.

Comment: I like the idea but I think it's not exactly what I'm looking for or understanding it so please bare with me. I've never really heard of CSS sprites so I could be a bit off here. Am I to make a location marker(within a sprite file) and then move that around with background-position or am I making a copy of my 500x500 map and that be my sprite map and I just display the 50x50 tile I want to on the rollover?

Comment: @Billy I'm sorry, I didn't read the question very well. I'm not sure I understand the question 100%, but after a second look it might be a rotator you want. Like, you have box a, and link a, link b, and link c. When User hovers link a, box a's background / or image changes, and when the hover link b, same thing but different, and so on. If this is what you want, you might need to modify one of the rotator scripts around. (you'll need JavaScript to do this without an utter hack) http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/examples/image-rotator/ <- http://designm.ag/tutorials/image-rotator-css-jquery/

Comment: Yeah the problem was hard to explain however my brother sent me a wake-up call that made go duh. I was looking for CSS image maps. So what I do is just parse a lot of data and the image map is made on the fly. Displaying the information that I need. Thx though for the ideas, I actually liked the rotator and sprite idea and may use that for something else. :)